# Firebase DB - Allow access on collection nodes just for owner users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know if my problem could be solved using firebase DB rules, this is the question:

**How can I write rules to make firebase just respond the requests related to an authenticated user?**

I have 2 collections `users` and `requests`. Each `user` has a `requests` object and each `requests` object has a `users` object in order to connect both collections. A `request` is related to two `users`.

bellow are the structures

```
{
"users": {
    "user1": {
        "requests": {
            "req1": true,
            "req2": true
        }
    },
    "user2": {
        "requests": {
            "req1": true
        }
    }
},
"requests": {
    "req1": {
        users: {
            user1: true,
            user2: true
        }
    },
    "req2": {
        users: {
            user1: true,
            user3: true
        }
    }
}}
```

I have a rule to **.read/.write**, but this works only if I request to `/requests/someId`:

```
{
  "requests": {
    "$request_id": {
      ".read": "data.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
      ".write": "data.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
}}
```

I've been trying lots of combinations of rules but I cannot get just the `requests` related to a `user` when I ask for `/requests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use rules to 'filter' results. You can only send a query to nodes of the database where this user has access to.

The solution is to split things up. Let's say you have a collection with these keys:
A, B, C, D, E, F, G

For user ER4521, you need to make a node ER4521/collection with as content:
B, D, F, G

First request would be to get the collection if ER4521/collection
And then send a request for each result to get all information about B, D, F and G.

Or you're going to use cloud functions which duplicates a collection to the userid/collection.

Regards, Peter

Comment: Here is the documentation of Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters